# Is this 'preposition?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I saw somebody say that 'because' used in subordinate clauses as in "I left because I was tired" is preposition.
I have considered 'because' as not a 'preposition' but a 'conjunction'.
What do you think of this? 'preposition' or 'conjunction' in this sentence like "I left  because I was tired."?

Comment: What does the [**dictionary**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/because?s=t) tell you about the word _because?_  Do you see an example at that link that looks the same as _I left because I was tired?_

Comment: Traditional grammar analyses it as a (subordinating) conjunction. But some modern grammars see it as a preposition, a view that I personally support but one that is somewhat controversial.  It's too big a topic to discuss here, but here's a link to an article by the eminent linguist/grammarian Geoff Pullum which explains the rationale behind calling it a prep: [link](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=9494). Only one dictionary that I'm aware of is forward-thinking enough to support the claim that it is a prep: [link](https://simple.wiktionary.org/wiki/because)

Comment: @Billj (I really must stop visiting ....) So now some traditional grammars regard it as a preposition too,  but only when it occurs with a noun phrase complement, right?

Comment: @P.E.Dant We should never use dictionaries for parts of speech. It's not what they're good for :(

Comment: @Araucaria Yes, you must, lol! Can you recall what Bas Aarts says about all this?

Comment: @BillJ He (OMEG, 2011) gives the CamGEL line. However, he also uses the term conjunctive preposition to describe prepositions that can take clauses as complements. His English Syntax and Argumentation (1997) already described words like *there* and *now* and other 'adverbs' as prepositions. Very unusual for an undergraduate textbook in its day, I believe.

Comment: Are we talking about **because** or **because of**?

Comment: I mean 'because' ,not because of.

Comment: @TRomano **because** is a preposition even in **because of [NOUN]**. In that construction **because** takes another Prepositional Phrase as a complement - *of [NOUN]*.

Comment: So it's a prepreposition?

Comment: *Because* is actually a prepositional phrase.  The grammarians are being confused by orthography.

Comment: @TRomano *because* is a preposition and heads the preposition phrase - *because of [NOUN]*.

Comment: @Man_From_India: I'm disagreeing. **because** is a prepositional phrase written as if it were a single word.

Comment: @TRomano hmmm have problem understanding, could you please explain?

Comment: @Man_From_India: **because** is really **by cause**.  The prepositional phrase `of-NOUN` identifies the cause, just as  in "He climbed the wall by means *of a ladder*" it identifies the means.   "He missed his flight because *of a computer glitch*".  Someday we might say "bemeans" and might see the "word" **bemeans** but that wouldn't change anything.

Comment: @TRomano I'm sorry, but still can't see how **because** is a preposition phrase :(

Comment: It is two words written as if they were one. The first of the two words is the preposition "by".

Comment: @TRomano oh now i see your logic. Hmmm.

Comment: @Araucaria Note that I asked the OP what the dictionary tells him. My comment was intentionally phrased as a question. The decision to rely upon a dictionary, or not, is the OP's.

Answer (score 2):

In modern grammar there is no difference between a subordinating conjunction and a preposition. We call both of these types of word prepositions in modern grammar. So the word *before* is the same word in the following three sentences:

- I've never seen her before.
- I saw her before the concert.
- I saw her before the concert started.

The word *because* is therefore a preposition in the OP's sentence.

Comment: I think the core of the argument is two-fold: (1) subordinators function as markers of subordination, whereas preps function as heads of the constituents they introduce and (2), unlike conjunctions, most preps have independent meaning ('an evident semantic content'). There's the further point that with items like "because" and "before" they uncontroversially occur as prepositions when they have an NP as complement, and there's no basis for assigning them to different categories according as they take an NP or a clause - or no complement at all.